# Расшифровка CryptoStream в с++

Tags: c++, .net, qt, шифрование

Есть файл зашифрованный с помощью класса CryptoStream (.NET Framework).
Можно узнать какой его расшифровать, если ключ(Key) и инит вектор(IV) известны?
Пишу программу на плюсах в QT.

```
var cryptic = new DESCryptoServiceProvider
{
    Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Key"),
    IV = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("IV")
};
var crStream = new CryptoStream(stream, cryptic.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
```

Хотелось бы узнать как такое рассшифровать? Понял что CreateEncryptor() создает [AES](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) шифрование. Но не понял что такое IV.

Answer (score 2):

`CryptoStream` не шифрует данные сам по себе - он просто предоставляет потоковый интерфейс интерфейс (Stream) поверх готового `ICryptoTransform`.

Т.е. нет никакого готового, вшитого в CryptoStream алгоритма. Найдите у себя в коде конкретный `ICryptoTransform`, передаваемый в конструктор CryptoStream - и напишите соответствующий код расшифровки.

Скорее всего у вас будет использоваться один из стандартных ICryptoTransform-оберток поверх Cryptography API, так что достаточно будет вызвать тот же алгоритм через [плюсовую версию Cryptography API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380255(v=vs.85).aspx).